# How to customize error message of maxlength with jQuery validate to show number of entered characters

Tags: jquery, validation, custom-errors

I want the `maxlength` validation of jQuery validate to display an error message like the following:

"Please enter no more than {0} characters. You've currently entered {1} characters."

Where `{1}` is a placeholder for the actual amount.
What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to do that but I found a workaround for you. I guess you could write your own validator for that field but this may be simpler.

Start by changing the default message for `maxlength` errors:

```
$.extend($.validator.messages, {  
    maxlength: $.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters. You've currently entered CHARS_NO characters.")
});
```

Keep the validation as usual, but add this function:

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    var rules = $(this).rules();
    if (rules.maxlength !== undefined && !$(this).valid()) {
        var errorLabel = $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + '][generated=true].error');
        errorLabel.text(errorLabel.text().replace('CHARS_NO', $(this).val().length));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here's the [working demo](http://stuff.rajchel.pl/stackoverflow/maxlength_validate.html) for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're triggering the validation, but the `maxlength` attribute on an `input` will preclude the user from entering more characters than whatever that value indicates.  So, it won't be necessary to inform the user that they've entered more characters than `maxlength` since they simply can't do it.

Can you provide additional context and/or details?

Comment: It's used in an textarea where there is no way to limit the actual amount of characters you can enter. Also note that I'm using the validate plug-in for jQuery.